# How to measure Menorah height

Tags: chanuka, menora-chanukia, halacha, shiurim-measurements

A menorah should preferably be within 10 tefachim from the ground (though higher than 3 tefachim). Are these ten tefachim measured to the base of the menorah, or to its top, or to the actual level of the flame (e.g., if glass inserts are used)?

Comment: What if you lit the flame too high, but as the candle burned down it became less than 20 amot: is that a problem of Hanacha Oseh Mitzva?

Comment: @DoubleAA , From the halacha it seems it has to be lit in a kosher place and if not one would have to blow it out and re lite it,so even though it eventualy will be in a kosher place it was lit in a non koshe place ,and the mitzvah is the lighting.

Comment: @DoubleAA, also see Rama on this inyun.

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning is that at that height there is more pirsumei nisa since one who needs the candles for light would normally place it higher.  That would seem to indicate that the light (flame) should be at that height.  Conversely, a candle hanging down from above 20 amos would be OK accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The Sharyai Tzion 671:33 Says in the name of the Pri Megadim that if the flame exceeds 20 amos it is pasul. So I would assume he would extend this halacha to ten tefachim as well.